# SVG Clipping: Firefox ignores transformation of clipping shape

Tags: css, firefox, svg, css-transforms, clip-path

I have an SVG with four coloured blocks that I want to clip by a rotated ellipse. It works as expected in Chrome and Safari, but Firefox (63.0.3 on Mac) ignores the transformation of the ellipse.

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/psychonaut85/pen/zMyLjO) that illustrates the issue.

SVG

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <ellipse id = "ellipse" cx="250" cy="250" rx="200" ry="100" />
    </clipPath>   
  </defs>

  <g class="clip-this">
    <rect class="color-1" x="0" y="0" width="250" height="250" />
    <rect class="color-2" x="250" y="0" width="250" height="250" />
    <rect class="color-3" x="0" y="250" width="250" height="250" />
    <rect class="color-4" x="250" y="250" width="250" height="250" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
#ellipse{
  transform:rotate(-30deg);
  transform-origin:center;
}
.color-1,.color-4{
    fill:#ababab;
}
.color-2,.color-3{
    fill:#3a3a3a;
}
svg {
    max-width: 400px;
}
.clip-this{
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1323962). As a workaround, you can use the SVG transform *attribute* instead of the CSS property. Note that for full browser compatibility the [transform function](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute) must not have units for the numbers, and the center of rotation is noted in userspace coordinates.

```css
.color-1,.color-4{
 fill:#ababab;
}
.color-2,.color-3{
 fill:#3a3a3a;
}
svg {
 max-width: 400px;
}
.clip-this{
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <ellipse id = "ellipse" cx="250" cy="250" rx="200" ry="100" transform="rotate(-30, 250, 250)" />
    </clipPath>   
  </defs>

  <g class="clip-this">
    <rect class="color-1" x="0" y="0" width="250" height="250" />
    <rect class="color-2" x="250" y="0" width="250" height="250" />
    <rect class="color-3" x="0" y="250" width="250" height="250" />
    <rect class="color-4" x="250" y="250" width="250" height="250" />
  </g>
</svg>
```